# Qt Version Ambiguity?

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, version, qtserialport

I've installed the latest version of Qt for Ubuntu x64. (http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.0/5.0.2/qt-linux-opensource-5.0.2-x86_64-offline.run)
When i checked the version from Qt Creator's About section its written "*Based on Qt 5.0.2 (64 bit)*". But when checked from terminal by "qmake --version" this time its "*Using Qt version 4.8.6*"
Which version of qt i am actually using?

Why do i ask this question: i've also installed Qtserialport. But i cant add "project.pro" file *QT+=serialport*(which is needed for Qt5x) that gave a makefile error. Only *CONFIG+=serialport*(which is needed for Qt4x) is allowed.

also i have:
Qt Creator version is 2.7.0
Qmake version is 2.0.1a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt Creator is an IDE. It can be used with multiple Qt versions. The Qt version it is based on itself is not relevant unless you're planning on expanding Qt Creator itself.

You can (and often will!) have multiple Qt versions installed in parallel. You "choose" them for a given project by running given Qt version's qmake. Qt Creator does that for you when you select the project configurations. That qmake can be in your path, but doesn't have to be. And if you have multiple versions installed, only the first `qmake` found in the path will be the default, the others have to be invoked manually.

When you configure your project in Qt Creator, you can choose what Qt versions you wish to build it with (at least one version, but it can be literally dozens!).

Same goes for when you build from the command line: you make a build directory, go there, then run selected qmake on your project's sources.

Suppose that you have Qt 4.7.4 in `/Qt/4.7.4` and Qt 5.7.0 in `/Qt/5.7.0`, and your project's sources are in `~/src/project`. You wish to build using both versions. Then:

```
# 4.7.4 build
mkdir -p ~/build/project-4.7.4
cd ~/build/project-4.7.4
/Qt/4.7.4/bin/qmake ~/src/project
make -j
# 5.7.0 build
mkdir -p ~/build/project-5.7.0
cd ~/build/project-5.7.0
/Qt/5.7.0/bin/qmake ~/src/project
make -j
```

Comment: thanks for useful information. i found qt4 under usr/include and usr/share. i think they were installed automatically with ubuntu. do i need to uninstall qt4 that confuses qt creator, what do you suggest?

Comment: **No!! Don't uninstall anything**. Qt4 doesn't "confuse" anything. When you use Qt Creator, **you** have to select what versions of Qt the Creator should be aware of, and for *each project*, **you** select what version it's to be built with. There's no confusion, only lack of configuration on your side. Qt Creator is designed to work with any number of Qt versions, it holds no favorites. It merely auto-detects some versions in common locations. The others you have to tell it about!